# luvit - не открывается. Я не имею понятия почему

Tags: lua, package

> $ ./luvit

> **bash: ./luvit: cannot execute: required file not found**

Хотелось бы знать что служит тригером проблемы.

Comment: Как ты его установил?  Где оказался собранный файл `luvit`?

Comment: Собственно... Я решил проблему через `proot-distro` установив дестребутив *linux*: `ubuntu` без графического интерфейса, только консоль с некоторыми ограничениями без рут прав, а целом проблема в том ято он не смог открыть файл иза кодировки, а при попытке измены кодировки файл вообще выдавал ошибку которая здесь не поместится, после установки `luvit-binary` на `proot-distro` все стало хорошо.

Comment: `не смог открыть файл иза кодировки` - из-за кодировки букв в имени файла?

Comment: Не уверен что я правильно выразился. В общем там внутри файла есть код который открывает линукс, но мобильная версия линукса не открывает так как нужны рут права, без понятия почему, на телефоне с рут правами все было ок, а без рут не ок, а без рута спасает только `proot-distro` и установка специального `luvit-binary`: https://github.com/truemedian/luvit-bin